# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() &&& Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I took a copy of my wordpress folder with its database and I put it on another PC but the site does not work and it shows me the following error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in C:\wamp\www\ccitnch\wp-includes\functions.php on line 1358

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_close() in C:\wamp\www\ccitnch\wp-includes\load.php on line 640

Answer (score 0):

The method you used for transferring the site from one PC to another is wrong and that's why you're facing the errors. Try this and it should work fine:

Install the [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin on the original site.

Next, generate a Duplicator package (via the plug-in's menu on wp-admin dashboad).

Once the package is generated, download the two package files (installer.php and the archive/zip file). Next, copy these two files to the other/destination PC/folder where you wish to create the site. Next, open the following link in your browser (on the destination PC):

{localhost}{path_to_the_new_site}/installer.php

and follow on-screen instructions. Your site should get created and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i solved my problem.
Your solution is good but it's not the best solution because i find just header and footer of the site.
my problem is in summary a plugin who causes this problem then i delete this plugin and i used my method classic of transfert and ok all is good.
 :)